# Mysql 'Not Like' wildcard more than two queries

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get results of wildcard with 'Not like'

When I wrote it on this

```
select * from Customers
where (Country  like 'Ger%' or Country like 'Mex%');
```

and I have tested it on 
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_like_not

It seems working fine but when I decided to go for 'NOT LIKE'

```
select * from Customers
where (Country  NOT like 'Ger%' or Country  NOT like 'Mex%');
```

It unable to get a result, as it does not remove anything to Ger or Mex. I have tried on.

```
select * from Customers
where Country  NOT like 'Ger%';
```

It seems working and they are able to remove Ger%

I have tried union, And few function but seems it does not get anything results I want.

Answer (score 0):

An Awkard moment for me as I got it. I seems forgot about 'and'

```
select * from Customers
where (Country  NOT like 'Ger%' and Country NOT like 'Mex%');
```